# Populate nested view in stateprovider

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

[Here is a plunker I am working on](https://plnkr.co/edit/v8VT6xQ5phqX4Bnn3e44?p=preview). I am new to stateProvider and I am trying my hands on nested view. I am pretty much I've messed up view inside view by doing:

```
.state('canvas',{
            name: 'canvas',
            url: '/',
            views:{
                '': {templateUrl:'welcome-page.html'},
                'carousel1@canvas': {
                    templateUrl: 'carousel-detail.html',
                    views:{
                        'carouselDetail@carousel1' : {template: '<h2>Carousel-1 child view</h2>'}
                          }
                },
                'carousel2@canvas': {template: '<h2>Carousel2</h2>'},
            },
})
```

Can you please help me render `carouselDetail` view.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Strictly speaking, you can't.

First, you can't have a view nested inside a view - meaning no child views inside view, **without** declaring a child state. So your `carousel1` and `carousel2` can be sibling views, but you cant have `carousel1-child` as its 'child view' of `carousel1` without having it declared as a child state. If you want a nested view, you have to declare a child state, and use `<div ui-view></div>` to populate the child views. You can read the docs [here](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/Multiple-Named-Views).

Second, assuming you are going to declare a child state, then you will run into a problem again - you will lose the parallelity (is there such a word?) of `carousel1` and `carousel2`. Why? Because you can't have two states that is active at the same time - and that's actually a strict definition of a state machine, and this is exactly what `ui-router` is doing. However, if you really want to have parallel states, use [ui-router-extra](https://github.com/christopherthielen/ui-router-extras) by christopherthielen. This extension of ui-router allows you to have multiple states active at one time, and might be the use case you want.

I have created a [plnkr](https://plnkr.co/edit/fYiygBl1LTYqFEnLipEq?p=preview) for you.

*Extra: When you post your plnkr, check that it is really reproducible the issue you wanna raise - there are multiple 404 error simply because you copy paste your file path.*

Comment: Thanks, will take care next time.